# ECS Container connect to service on the same EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have 1 ECS cluster running 1 EC2 instance. I start a APM server (Signoz) on EC2 (ssh into EC2 and install using command line). I have a program running as ECS task. I try to connect this program to APM server using localhost. But it fail with connection timeout. (ECS cluster and task are all run on EC2 type)

How to connect from ECS tasks to service run on EC2? I thought they are on the same instance?

Comment: Inside a docker container `localhost` refers to the container, not the host server. You need to use the private DNS name of the EC2 instance instead of `localhost`.

Comment: Thank Mark! Problem solve!